# Making a circle using lines in java

Tags: java, math, geometry, lines

I've checked all the other questions related to this and they haven't helped me. I'm not trying to make a duplicate question. I need to create a circle in java using lines (9 to be exact for that im working on right now).
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6faPD.png)

```
int points = 9;
int r = 100;
float originX = width/2+r;
float originY = height/2;
float angle1;
float angle2;

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
    for(int i=0; i < points;++i) {
        angle1 = i * 2 * PI / points;
        angle2 = i * 2 * PI / points;
        line(originX + r * cos( angle1), originY + r * sin(angle1),
             originX + r * cos( angle2), originY + r * sin(angle2));
    }
}
```

That is the formula and I know the **circumfrence** of a circle is **2pi radians** so I was using `(2*pi)/9` as my theta for both.
My current code is located above .

Can someone tell me how to get this working?

Comment: Please just add your code and formula in text as opposed to links to imgs. Also, please explain what the problem is; what is it doing/not doing that's unexpected?

Comment: I apologize I'm not very familiar with this site I've just started using it and I'm also rushing a bit which is why I posted them as pictures. The program is supposed to look like this http://puu.sh/s5WxM/621d92ae96.jpg (that one has to be a picture obviously :p) currently it is making some wonky lines and doing completely not what I need it too.

Comment: Just trying to help you get help. The code in the image isn't complete (i.e.; won't compile). Adding a link to an img that's an img is fine but if you put actual text code people can and will run it on their own machines and help you.

Comment: Alright I tried to fix it a little :)

Comment: This is java? Wheres the class definition?

Comment: This should be something that takes me 10 minutes but I've been working on it for over 4 hours I think and I've gotten no where. The program I'm using is processing, as far as I know it doesn't require classes for what I'm doing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are drawing the spokes of a wheel, rather that the circumference. To do this you want to draw a line from the i-th point to the (i+1)-th point

```
for(int i=0; i < points;++i) {
    angle1 = i * 2 * Pi / points;
    angle2 = (i+1) * 2 * Pi / points;
    line(OriginX + r * cos( angle1), OriginY + r * sin(angle1),
         OriginX + r * cos( angle2), OriginY + r * sin(angle2)) ;
}
```

Comment: What does angle1 and angle2 refer to?

Comment: This is what i get after implementing and running the code http://puu.sh/s5Wmn/d157241c42.png

Comment: I realized why this may be Salix. In the code you provided angle1 and angle2 are equal

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING ME?!?!?!?. That was the first thing I tried when I started doing this whole thing. I forgot the brackets. You've got to be kidding me. When you posted your answer I tried that as well but again forgot the brackets.

Comment: Just have to do part B now which is having points be mouseX/10 and having the circle continuously redraw on the screen with a different amount of points.